# "Cписание" и "поступление" одним словом

Tags: одним-словом

В бухгалтерской терминологии есть списания и поступления средств на счет и со счета. Есть ли слово, которое объединяет эти два понятия не заостряя внимание на направлении их движения?

Answer (score 6):

It's *движение*: *движение денежных средств* in case of a financial account, *движение металла* in case of a metal account etc.

> Движение денежных средств: изменение сумм денежных средств на счетах физических и юридических лиц, переход денег из одних рук в другие. // *Райзберг Б.А., Лозовский Л.Ш., Стародубцева Е.Б.. Современный экономический словарь. — 2-е изд., испр. М.: ИНФРА-М. 479 с.. 1999.*

Comment: With all respect, I disagree. Arguably, *движение* is about resources moving *between* end points. *Списание* and *зачисление* refer to one point only.

Comment: @texnic: you're right, this term's use in accounting is not quite coherent. However, bad as it may be, it is used in accounting in this very sense: a hypernym for credit and debit. Also note that all modern accounting adheres to the principle of double-entry bookkeeping system: this means that all the monetary transactions you reflect should have at least two endpoints. Even if you literally blow your money away in the wind, you reflect it with a double entry: you credit your pocket money asset account and debit your expenses account.

Answer (score 2):

Ближайшее, вероятно, «транзакция», хотя это не совсем одно и то же. Транзакция, как правило, подразумевает, что деньги откуда-то ушли и куда-то пришли. Списание допускает, по крайней мере умозрительно, что деньги могли уйти, но никуда не прийти. Но на практике слово транзакция можно применять вместо списания и зачисления. Например:

> «Непонятная транзакция»
>
> «Вижу в выписке транзакцию на сумму *xxx*»

В обоих случаях остаётся неясным, о зачислении или списании идёт речь, т.е. слово «транзакция» действительно заменяет оба термина.

Comment: или операция....

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка, хорошее слово, но не совсем то же, мне кажется. Транзакция — это операция по переводу денег, поэтому более точно соответствует вопросу. Операция — это более широкое понятие. Например, покупка — это тоже операция, но не транзакция.

Comment: "Покупка" с позиций состояния счёта операцией не является, она обезличена простым изменением количества средств. А можно ли трактовать как "транзакцию" такой случай _поступления_ средств как **начисление процентов** или внесение средств наличными деньгами?